# Was the names of the hot springs in ep8 of Gugure! Kokkuri-san a joke/reference to another anime?

Tags: gugure-kokkuri-san

While searching for the hot spring that can turn him back into male, Kokkuri-san passes several other hot springs. I got the feeling from watching the show that they were giving a shout-out to / parodying other anime shows.

What were those shows?

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted some screenshot as reference to these types of questions.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ It would help a lot in the posting of those screenshots if CR didn't DRM the videos... X<(

Comment: Glossary: CR = CrunchyRoll; DRM = Digital Rights Management. anime.SE = this very site. And before you cry wolf, I watch CR and post to anime.SE in/from my android tablet. (also note that this post does not have an @___ adresee)

Comment: @Midwin regardless of DRM or not, you can still take screenshots from your computer, if you are on Windows 7 or above, you can use the built-in "Snipping Tool"

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Not using windows. Android 4.4.4 here. Unless I root the tablet, no can do.

Comment: You should be able to press and hold the "Power" and "Volume Down" buttons together for about 3 seconds to take a screenshot without a third party app. The should be in the Gallery App under "Screenshots."

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Yes, I am aware. Since it is a samsung device, sweeping the hand also takes a screenshot, but in both methods the device just pops a message saying "impossible take screenshot. Contents protected by DRM".

Comment: if you can't do that then at least include the time code for when this happened. Any sort of reference is fine so ppl don't have to dig through the entire episode to find what you're talking about.

Comment: It is from around 18:00, if I'm not mistaken. Just had to close the tab to reduce memory usage, and I forgot to take a second look to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed these two signs:

[image: Panda Spring]

[image: Woman Spring]

To me, that's a clear reference to the classic [Ranma 1/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranma_%C2%BD), as that series features a male protagonist who fell into a cursed spring, which made him turn into a woman whenever he got splashed with cold water. His father likewise received the same curse and turned into a panda after falling into a different spring in the same area.

[image: Ranma 1/2]

Comment: Yup. Ya hit the bullseye.